# About Variables Used Within BasicBlock

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to ask a question about LLVM IR language. For a basicblock, variables used are always loaded prior to usage, and stored after usage. Two example basic blocks are as follows:

```
 %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i8**, align 8
  %i = alloca i32, align 4
  %fact = alloca i32, align 4
  %n = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1
  store i32 %argc, i32* %2, align 4
  store i8** %argv, i8*** %3, align 8
  %4 = load i8*** %3, align 8
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds i8** %4, i64 1
  %6 = load i8** %5, align 8
  %7 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* bitcast (i32 (...)* @atoi to i32 (i8*, ...)*)(i8* %6)
  store i32 %7, i32* %n, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %fact, align 4
  store i32 1, i32* %i, align 4
  br label %8


  %9 = load i32* %i, align 4
  %10 = load i32* %n, align 4
  %11 = icmp sle i32 %9, %10
  br i1 %11, label %12, label %19
```

For control flow, define first basic block as A, second basic block as B, control flow is from A to B.

I wonder, for the usage of %7, program store %7 to %n pointer in A, and load %n pointer to %10 to get access to it, which are like:

```
store i32 %7, i32* %n, align 4

%10 = load i32* %n, align 4

%11 = icmp sle i32 %9, %10
```

I wonder if I could just DROP store and load instructions, and directly use value %7, which is as follows:

```
%11 = icmp sle i32 %9, %7
```

Is this OK? Could anyone talk about the reason behind it?

My description may be obscure. I could explain it more clear if you have questions on it.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you think you can't do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to refer to virtual registers from other basic blocks.

Since you provided an incomplete example, I can just speculate if `%7` can be directly used in the comparison:

If you optimize the code with LLVM's opt tool, the register will probably not be stored and reloaded and the comparison will directly use `%7` (or a phi function dependent on the value).

You can try the mem2reg register pass:

```
opt -mem2reg <your file>.ll -o <target file>.ll
```